# How to get related data from two tables while there are two Foreign keys related to One Primary key in Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, eloquent-relationship

The question that I want to ask looks silly but it took more than 4 days of my life and I'm still struggling with this problem and I found no good solution up to this point!

As you see in the image I attached, there are two tables named **"`Contacts`"** and **"`Users`"**.

Each user can send contact request to other users if there are no previous/pending incoming or outgoing contact requests from target users.

For example, `USER_1` can send contact request to `USER_2` if there is no pending request from `USER_2` to `USER_1`.

If any of `USER_1` or `USER_2` has already sent contact request and other user accepted the request, then they are in each other's contacts list!

Now, I want to get data from **`Users`** and **`Contacts`** tables at the same time in Laravel Eloquent or any other methods in the Laravel Framework.

**For Example** if `USER_1` has sent contact request to `USER_2` **AND** `USER_2` accepted the contact request, I want to show **`USER_1`** name and profile in **`USER_2`** contact list **AND** I want to show **`USER_2`** name and profile in **`USER_1`** contact list.

I know it's confusing but I really want to find a solution for this problem to proceed with this project. Also if there is any problem with naming convention for table columns PLEASE let me know or give me better suggestion.

If anybody is there who can help me, please don't hesitate and post your answer. Thank you.

I also attached some codes that I tried up to this point and yes it did not work properly:

**I created local scope method in Contacts Model and added this code**

```
public function scopeContacts ($query) {
        return $query->join('users', function ($join) {
            $join->on('contacts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->on('contacts.target_id', '=', 'users.id');
        })
        ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('status', '=', 'accepted')
        ->orWhere('target_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('status', '=', 'accepted')
        ->get();
}
```

Code above returns null or empty array!

[image]

Comment: how about we restructure your table?

Users

Contact


Contact_Users Table (pivot table not incrementing)
users_id
contacts_id
status

would be easier to eloquent and create scopes

Comment: @PendejoTrax Sorry I didn't get it. You mean I should change user_id and target_id in Contacts table to user_id and contacts_id?

Comment: I mean add another table. and your scope will be from that 3rd new table(Pivot) which has status approved or rejected

Comment: @PendejoTrax Yeah I will try it. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a pivot table called contact_users that may contain user_id and contact_id.

This is because, when you have to communicate two (or more) `n:n` tables you MUST create a pivot table.

Laravel support this by providing the `belongsToMany()` method, read more [HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Laravel docs gives a great example that can help you.

Comment: I received another answer exactly like what you said and I'm trying it but I'm confused. There are two FKs in `contacts` table named `user_id` and `target_id`. When you say a pivot table should containd `user_id` and `contact_id`, which of FKs should be inserted under `user_id` of contact_user table? Just in case if you are confused with my question, I should mention that both `user_id` and `target_id` in `contacts` table, are FK on `ID` of `users` table! One can be the user who receives request and other one can be the user who sends the request!